# How to flatten the result of a nested split in a C# Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Given the string "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i", I would like to split the string into a flat list of two columns, one each for the key (to the left of the colon) and values (comma separated to the right of the colon). The result should look like this.

```
{
    Key: "a",
    Value: "b"
},
{
    Key: "c",
    Value: "d"
},
{
    Key: "c",
    Value: "e"
},
{
    Key: "f",
    Value: "g"
},
{
    Key: "f",
    Value: "h"
},
{
    Key: "f",
    Value: "i"
}
```

The problem is that I cannot flatten the results of the second split on the comma across all keys, so that I return a single list of KeyValue, rather than a list of a list of KeyValue.

```
public class KeyValue {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<KeyValue> mc = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i"
    .Split(';')
    .Select(a =>
    {
        int colon = a.IndexOf(':');
        string left = a.Substring(0, colon);
        string right = a.Substring(colon + 1);
        List<KeyValue> result = right.Split(',').Select(x => new KeyValue { Key = left, Value = x }).ToList();
        return result;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want a list of a list of KeyValue? Your sample is just a list of KeyValue.

Comment: @SamLeach, I want just a list of KeyValue, but notice that the value is the individual values in the CSV to the right of the colons split on the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were *very* close.  The method to flatten a sequence of sequences is `SelectMany`.  We could add one to the end of your existing code, but since it already ends with a `Select`, we can in fact just change it to a `SelectMany` and we're done:

```
List<KeyValue> mc = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i"
    .Split(';')
    .SelectMany(a =>
    {
        int colon = a.IndexOf(':');
        string left = a.Substring(0, colon);
        string right = a.Substring(colon + 1);
        List<KeyValue> result = right.Split(',')
            .Select(x => new KeyValue { Key = left, Value = x }).ToList();
        return result;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValue> mc = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i"
    .Split(';')
    .Select(a =>
    {
        int colon = a.IndexOf(':');
        string left = a.Substring(0, colon);
        string right = a.Substring(colon + 1);
        return new KeyValue() { Key = left, Value = right };
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Just for claification the `Select` projects a list onto a new type; it already handles the `List` creation for you. Therefore you were asking for a `List` of `List` objects. All you need to ask of is the object, in this case `KeyValue`.

Comment: I think your solution is missing the third split on `Value = right`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a new `List<KeyValue> result`. You want to just return a `KeyValue` as below

```
string data = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i";

var mc = data
    .Split(';')
    .Select(a =>
    {
        int colon = a.IndexOf(':');
        string left = a.Substring(0, colon);
        string right = a.Substring(colon + 1);
        return new KeyValue() { Key = left, Value = right };
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think your solution is missing the third split on `Value = right`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As always, it can be performed via Linq :

```
string s = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i";
string Last = "";
var Result = s.Split(';', ',').Select(x =>
{
    if (x.Contains(":"))
    {
        Last = x.Split(':')[0];
        return new { Key = x.Split(':')[0], Value = x.Split(':')[1] };
    }
    else return new { Key = Last, Value = x };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = "a:b;c:d,e;f:g,h,i";

var mc = data
    .Split(';')
    .SelectMany(x => {
        int separatorIndex = x.IndexOf(':');
        var key = x.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
        var values = x.Substring(separatorIndex + 1).Split(',');

        return values.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key, v));
    });
```

[image: Result of transform]